# Hibernate oneToOne mapping not reading joinColumn class instance

Tags: java, hibernate

```
package com.hibernatetest;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ctry_id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "ctry_name")
private String name;


@Transient
private int rank;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="fk_cont_id")
private Continent continent;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="country")
private HeadOfState hos;

public HeadOfState getHos() {
    return hos;
}

public void setHos(HeadOfState hos) {
    this.hos = hos;
}

public Continent getContinent() {
    return continent;
}

public Country() {
    ;
}
public Country(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setContinent(Continent continent) {
    this.continent = continent;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setRank(int rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
}

public int getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public void addCountryToDb(Continent cont) {
    continent = cont;
}

}


package com.hibernatetest;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="hos")
public class HeadOfState {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="hos_id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="hos_name")
private String name;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="fk_ctry_id")
private Country country;

public HeadOfState() {

}

public HeadOfState(String name) {
    this.name=name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Country getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(Country country) {
    this.country = country;
}



}

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
    Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
    Country countObj = (Country)session.get(Country.class, 62);
    HeadOfState hos = new HeadOfState("ghanaKing");
    hos.setCountry(countObj);
    transaction.begin();
    session.save(hos);
    transaction.commit();

    Country cont = (Country)session.get(Country.class, 62);
    System.out.println("name of country is "+cont.getName());
    System.out.println("name of continent is "+cont.getContinent().getName());
    HeadOfState newhos = cont.getHos();
    if (newhos == null) {
        throw new Exception("hos obj is null even after storing it");
    }
    System.out.println("Name of HOS is "+cont.getHos().getName());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("exception has happened: "+ex.getMessage());
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        session.close();
        HibernateUtil.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Output of the SQL table even with the exception in the code

```
ysql> select * from hos;
host_id, hos_name, fk_ctry_id
2,       ghanaKing,62
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from country
ctry_id, ctry_name, fk_cont_id
60, England, 30
62, ghana, 30
```

Eclipse exception

```
name of country is ghana
name of continent is Asia
exception has happened hos obj is null even after storing it

Nov 24, 2014 2:54:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://172.23.180.81:3306/test]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: hos obj is null even after storing it
    at com.hibernatetest.SqlTest.main(SqlTest.java:37)
```

Comment: The formatting is so skewed. I am new to stackoverlow and seriously confused on how to format it. The issue is that in the above code, I am able to store the values for HeadOfState accurately, but in the same code when I try to fetch the values, I get an exception that the object does not exist. Basically, I retrieve the country object and it has the HeadOfState object hos and it comes out as null for some reason. Even though the DB table has the record

Comment: Try `session.persist` instead of `session.save`

Comment: Please note that in your DB, in hos table, you have column host_id and in your mapping class you have the following: @Column(name="hos_id")

Answer (score 0):

try to set related objects on both sides of association.
When you save your instances :

```
hos.setCountry(countObj);
```

and add

```
countObj.setHos(hos);
```

You could add a convinient method to either of your instances like, therefore you would call one method insead of two.

Comment: thanks but the problem is somewhere else(without changing the code much from what i posted). In the class that has the main method where exception occurs, when i run that class with main, if in the first run, i do session.save and as u see when i retrieve further down, i get the exception that i am talking about. But in the next run, if i just try to retrieve the saved objects, it works perfectly. the problem is something else i suppose